# writing values to cell in a row in excel for a class variable in python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, xlwt

I have been trying to write values to a #1 in the excel sheet from which data is generated. I don't get any error or anything as such but neither do i get any output in the excel file.

Also is there a easy way to find the row/column is the cell pointing to ?

Below i have my code written for counting a specific word from html and those values need to be put in a excel file.

```
from xlwt import Workbook
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from xlwt import Workbook
from collections import Counter


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("fetch dashboard link")
login_test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="authContent"]/form/div/p[2]/a')
login_test.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)    
a = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")




wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Automation')
sheet1.write_merge(0,2,0,0,'#')

sheet1.write_merge(0,0,1,7,'Test Result')

sheet1.write(1,1,'Component')
sheet1.write(1,2,'Test Restult')
sheet1.write(1,3,'Pass')
sheet1.write(1,4,'Fail')
sheet1.write(1,5,'Cannot Test')
sheet1.write(1,6,'Pass With Concern')
sheet1.write(1,7,'Pending')

i = 3
j=1
for row_len in range (0,27):
    sheet1.write(i,0,j)
    i=i+1
    j=j+1






class counter_class:
    def count(self, tittle, block_code):
        blockcode_passed = block_code.count("Passed")
        blockcode_blocked = block_code.count("Blocked")
        blockcode_fail = block_code.count("Failed")
        blockcode_retest = block_code.count("Retest")
        blockcode_cannot_test = block_code.count("Cannot Test")
        blockcode_completed = block_code.count("Completed")
        blockcode_passwc = block_code.count("Pass With Concern")
        blockcode_untested = block_code.count("Untested")

        ##writing the count values fetched from the top to write it to a row in the excel file. 

        f_r=3
        f_c=1
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, tittle)
        f_c= f_c + 2
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, blockcode_passed)
        f_c= f_c + 1
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, blockcode_fail)
        f_c= f_c + 1
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, blockcode_cannot_test)
        f_c= f_c + 1
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, blockcode_cannot_test)
        f_c= f_c + 1
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, blockcode_passwc)
        f_c= f_c + 1
        sheet1.write(f_r, f_c, blockcode_untested)
        f_c=1
        f_r=4
        print f_r
        print f_c

wb.save('xlwtexample.xls')

##Apps gateway starts here
apps_gateway = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"group-3191427"})
apps_gateway_str = str(apps_gateway)
apps_gateway_obj=counter_class()
apps_gateway_obj.count("appsgateway",apps_gateway_str)
```